# With SystemJS, how do I map URLs between CDN libraries (CodeMirror)?

Tags: cdn, systemjs, codemirror

In my project, I want to use SystemJS to import a certain CodeMirror addon (`xml-fold`) from cdnjs.

However, that addon references main CodeMirror js through `../../lib/codemirror`. This is resolved as `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/lib/codemirror`, which is incorrect — should be `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/codemirror.js`.

I tried to `map` wrong URL to the correct one, but it does not seem to be picked up — see below (error in browser console):

```js
SystemJS.config({
    map: { 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/lib/codemirror': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/codemirror.js' }
});

// in actual project I import it through a dependency, but the problem is the same
SystemJS.import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/addon/fold/xml-fold.js');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.42/system.js"></script>
```

Error in console:

```
system.js:4 GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/lib/codemirror 403
```

What's the right way to map it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to define a package for codemirror in SystemJS configuration and remap `lib/codemirror` to `codemirror.js` using [package-local map setting:](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages)

```
SystemJS.config({
    map: {
        'codemirror': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0'
    },
    packages: {
        'codemirror': {
            map: {'./lib/codemirror':  './codemirror.js'}
        }
    }
});
```

This config should be enough to turn this import

```
SystemJS.import('codemirror/addon/fold/xml-fold');
```

into this url

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/addon/fold/xml-fold.js'
```

Then, relative path `../../lib/codemirror` referenced from it will stay in the same package and will be remapped to `./codemirror.js`. (I checked with current SystemJS version - 0.19.42)

You might also want to add

```
    main: 'codemirror.js'
```

to codemirror package config to be able to import codemirror itself as

```
 SystemJS.import('codemirror');
```

if you need to do that.

Comment: Thanks, however it's not just an extension. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/lib/codemirror.js does not exist, it has to be https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/4.2.0/codemirror.js (without lib).